# Why are Angular Material oversized relative to they way they appear material.angular.io?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Why do all my Angular Material components render as "giant size" in my Angular app?
Top is a image capture from the material website, below is the way the same controls are rendering inside my Angular App.

From material.angular.io
[image]

From my Angular site (FAB and minFAB)

[image]

Why are these buttons appearing ( a mat-mini-fab and a mat-fab so much larger than those on the Material io's website?  Also, see the size comparison above for a mat-card title and subtitle, compared to the way they render on the material.io website.

There's nothing special about the code, and no css applied.  To produce the smaller button its just

```
  <button mat-mini-fab color="accent">
      <mat-icon>plus_one</mat-icon>
    </button>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please supply the computed width and height for your FAB buttons?

Comment: Thanks for the question.  I didn't occur to me to check that relative to the dimensions on the material website.  They are same -- 40x40, which led me to check to see if that web page was zoomed, which I discovered it was.  Mystery solved.

Comment: Haha - gotta love that! I think this question can probably be closed or deleted then ?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how this happened, but the page opened zoomed out.  I think chrome may have "remembered" this somehow?  Anyway, checking the computed size of the elements as suggested by zza inspired me to check the zoom since the mat-mini-fab was the same pixel dimensions in both instances.